# ODOO 8 - Hot Code Push

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Is Hot code push feature (similar to meteor) available in ODOO 8 development? I mean when we make changes to python development file it should reflect in the ODOO modules automatically without restarting the server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in odoo8 with the `--auto-reload` parameter

It requires the [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) which is a Python module for monitoring filesystem changes.

just simply restart the odoo server like this

`odoo.py --other-parameters-you-want --auto-reload`

or in your configuration file set `auto_reload` to True